# I have an exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException with jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

```js
package asdf;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
public class asdasd {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         Validate.isTrue(args.length == 1, "usage: supply url to fetch");
            String url = args[0];
            print("Fetching %s...", url);

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
            Elements media = doc.select("[src]");
            Elements imports = doc.select("link[href]");

            print("\nMedia: (%d)", media.size());
            for (Element src : media) {
                if (src.tagName().equals("img"))
                    print(" * %s: <%s> %sx%s (%s)",
                            src.tagName(), src.attr("abs:src"), src.attr("width"), src.attr("height"),
                            trim(src.attr("alt"), 20));
                else
                    print(" * %s: <%s>", src.tagName(), src.attr("abs:src"));
            }

            print("\nImports: (%d)", imports.size());
            for (Element link : imports) {
                print(" * %s <%s> (%s)", link.tagName(),link.attr("abs:href"), link.attr("rel"));
            }

            print("\nLinks: (%d)", links.size());
            for (Element link : links) {
                print(" * a: <%s>  (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));
            }
        }

        private static void print(String msg, Object... args) {
            System.out.println(String.format(msg, args));
        }

        private static String trim(String s, int width) {
            if (s.length() > width)
                return s.substring(0, width-1) + ".";
            else
                return s;
        }




    }
```

This is my code. I am using jsoup and it's give me an error like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: usage: supply url to fetch
    at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.isTrue(Validate.java:45)
    at asdf.asdasd.main(asdasd.java:11)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like the `Validate.isTrue` method is checking if the `args.length == 1`, seeing that it's not, and throwing `IllegalArgumentException` as a result.

Therefore, if you pass in one argument, your argument array will look like this:

`arg[0] == "passed_argument"`

Comment: Thank you. This advice solves "atorg.jsoup.helper.Validate.isTrue(Validate.java:45)" error. But still there is a "at asdf.asdasd.main(asdasd.java:11)"problem.

Comment: It's still throwing `IllegalArgumentException` at line 11 after you've changed to args.length == 2 and still are passing in an argument?

Comment: How are you executing this program?

Comment: I solved that problem but I got one more question. I made an object with Document. I want use this function "str.contains(word)" for document . How can ı do it.

Comment: @Damnit If you have another question, please ask a new question.

Comment: I'm not sure what the OP is doing, but this answer is WRONG; Java does not put the program name in args[0]. C (and C++) does -- or at least tries to; on Unix it needs cooperation from the parent process, which common shells do but other programs might not. Shell scripts on Unix, and BAT files on Windows, also do $0 and %0 respectively. But not Java.